# How can I properly import a fixed-with ASCII file into R that has two different record types?

Tags: r, dataframe, ascii

I'm trying to extract the 2021 Hate Crime Master File from the Crime Data Explorer into R.
https://cde.ucr.cjis.gov/LATEST/webapp/#/pages/downloads (Scroll to Master File, select "Hate Crime" then "2021")

The file is a fixed-width, ASCII text format. The file contains two record types- Batch Headers and Incident Reports. Each Batch Header (BH) is followed by available hate crime incident reports (IR), and all incident reports following the batch header belong to the originating agency identifier (ORI) of the batch header. The batch header can be followed by another batch header, which means there was no incident data for the ORI.

I have seen some posts related to this data, but their end goal of extracting this data is different from mine. Ideally, I would like to import this data into R by creating multiple data frames, all with the same format, linked together. I would like each data frame to have the BH then following any incident reports. If there is a way to create a singular data frame then having subsets of incident reports under each batch header, that would work too. I have some knowledge of R, but I am no expert-could really use some help here on how to get started.

How would I go best extracting this data?

I've researched many articles, but haven't been able to find something that can get me started. My main issue is that I'd like all of the data- not just batch headers or just incident reports.

The first 100 lines of the data:

```
BH50AK0010100000000000000                ANCHORAGE                     AK1C941Y         3030020A         00028623800  38000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZIII    ANCHORAGE                     020            
IR50AK00101002W2MGU73SXX820210527 200100U2900011332I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000010000U
IR50AK00101002W2MGU73SY2 20210525 200001W2900010343B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000001U
IR50AK00101002W2MGU82JNB420210825 300301W13C0012014I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010020100U
IR50AK00101002W2MGU82S46820211104 400000U2900010422R                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000000U
IR50AK0010100PT-0WE0W4HCT20210429 200102I13A0011341I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000200N
BH50AK0010200000000000000        20210101FAIRBANKS                     AK4 941Y         3030020AA        00003059800 258000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZIZ    FAIRBANKS                     090            
IR50AK0010200CN0BAM5D728N20210802N300102I13A0011341I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000200U
IR50AK0010200CN0BIVMR728N20210813N300101W13C0011441I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR50AK0010200CN0BIWS9728N20210924N300001I2900010521B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000100N
BH50AK0010300000000000000                JUNEAU                        AK4 941N         3030020A         00003187400   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021I  I    JUNEAU                        110            
IR50AK0010300CN01REICT-8N20210202 100100U13B0011313I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000000U
IR50AK0010300Z91X J8ZU63920211229 400101B13B0015413I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
BH50AK0010400000000000000        20210101KETCHIKAN                     AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000819800   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZI    KETCHIKAN                     130            
IR50AK0010400CN-VAO5U728N20211003N400000U2900011126O                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000000 
BH50AK0010500000000000000        20210101KODIAK                        AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000577600   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    KODIAK                        150            
BH50AK0010600000000000000        20210101NOME                          AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000387100   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZIZ    NOME                          180            
IR50AK00106003I-MQ3QCZX I20210718N300100U23H0012041I       2900012041I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0010000000 
BH50AK0010700000000000000        20210101PETERSBURG                    AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000330200   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZIZZ    PETERSBURG                    195            
IR50AK0010700CN-BEOSU728N20210429N200101W13C0012412I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
BH50AK0010800000000000000        20210101SEWARD                        AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000295000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZIZ    SEWARD                        122            
IR50AK0010800CN-B-YZU728N20210922N300301W13B0032042I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0030000100U
BH50AK0010900000000000000        20210101SITKA                         AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000835300   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    SITKA                         220            
BH50AK0011000000000000000        20210101SKAGWAY                       AK7 941N         3030020AA        00000120200   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    SKAGWAY                       230            
BH50AK0011100000000000000        20210101WRANGELL                      AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000252200   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    WRANGELL                      275            
BH50AK0011200000000000000        20210101VALDEZ                        AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000384200   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    VALDEZ                        261            
BH50AK0011300000000000000        20210101BETHEL                        AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000671700   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    BETHEL                        050            
BH50AK0011400000000000000        20210101CORDOVA                       AK7 941N         3030020AA        00000216200   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    CORDOVA                       261            
BH50AK0011600000000000000        20210101KOTZEBUE                      AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000326400   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    KOTZEBUE                      188            
BH50AK0011700000000000000        20210101PALMER                        AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000797200  38000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZI    PALMER                        170            
IR50AK0011700PE2MPUH3I71A20211105N400101W13A0011171I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100 
BH50AK0011800000000000000        20210101BARROW                        AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000931000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    NORTH SLOPE BOROUGH           185            
BH50AK0011900000000000000                SELDOVIA                      AK7 941N         3030020A         00000028000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        SELDOVIA                      122            
BH50AK0012000000000000000        20210101SOLDOTNA                      AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000485500   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    SOLDOTNA                      122            
BH50AK0012100000000000000        20210101HAINES                        AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000262400   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    HAINES                        100            
BH50AK0012200000000000000        20210101HOMER                         AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000614300   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    HOMER                         122            
BH50AK0012300000000000000        20210101KENAI                         AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000797000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    KENAI                         122            
BH50AK0012400000000000000                ANCHORAGE                     AK7 941NAK00101003030020A 2021120100000000000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        SPENARD SERVICE DISTRICT      020            
BH50AK0012500000000000000        20210101METLAKATLA                    AK7 947N         3030020AA        000000000000  0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    METLAKATLA TRIBAL                            
BH50AK0012600000000000000        20210101FAIRBANKS                     AK7 945N         3030020AA        000000000000258000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    FAIRBANKS INTRNL AIRPORT                     
BH50AK0012700000000000000        20210101ANCHORAGE                     AK7 945N         3030020AA        000000000000 38000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZ Z    TED STEVENS ANCHORAGE INTERNAT               
BH50AK0012800000000000000                WHITTIER                      AK7 941N         3030020A         00000020300   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        WHITTIER                      261            
BH50AK0013000000000000000        20210101DILLINGHAM                    AK7 941N         3030020AA        00000232400   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    DILLINGHAM                    070            
BH50AK0013100000000000000                HOONAH                        AK7 941N         3030020A         00000080100   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        HOONAH                        105            
BH50AK0013200000000000000        20210101NORTH POLE                    AK7 941N         3030020AA        00000210600 258000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    NORTH POLE                    090            
BH50AK0013300000000000000        20210101UNALASKA                      AK6 941N         3030020AA        00000448400   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    UNALASKA                      016            
BH50AK0013500000000000000                KLAWOCK                       AK7 941N         3030020A         00000078100   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        KLAWOCK                       198            
BH50AK0014200000000000000        20210101FAIRBANKS                     AK7 943N         3030020AA        000000000000258000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    UNIV OF AK: FAIRBANKS                        
BH50AK0014300000000000000        20210101ANCHORAGE                     AK7 943N         3030020AA        000000000000 38000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    UNIV OF AK: ANCHORAGE                        
BH50AK0014500000000000000        20210101CRAIG                         AK7 941N         3030020AA        00000127300   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    CRAIG                         198            
BH50AK0014600000000000000        20210101KING SALMON                   AK7 941N         3030020AA        00000076900   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZZZ    BRISTOL BAY BOROUGH           060            
BH50AK0014700000000000000                KAKE                          AK7 941NAKAST01003030020A 2021120100000053600   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        KAKE                          198            
BH50AK0014900000000000000                NENANA                        AK7 941NAKAST01003030020A 2021120100000034000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        NENANA                        290            
BH50AK0015000000000000000                SAINT PAUL ISLAND             AK7 941N         3030020A         00000048600   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        ST. PAUL                      016            
BH50AK0015200000000000000                SAND POINT                    AK7 941N         3030020A         00000110000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        SAND POINT                    013            
BH50AK0015400000000000000                TOGIAK                        AK7 941NAKAST01003030020A 2021120100000082500   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        TOGIAK                        070            
BH50AK0015600000000000000        20210101WASILLA                       AK5 941N         3030020AA        00001148500  38000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZIZ    WASILLA                       170            
IR50AK0015600W81HPUOPZY1A20210821N300101W13C0012062I       2900011862I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0010000100N
IR50AK0015600W81HPUOZJ21A20210806N300101W13A0011812I                                                                                                                                                                         41                                                                              0010000100N
BH50AK0016300000000000000                ANVIK                         AK7 941NAKAST01003030020A 20211201000000078000  0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        ANVIK                                        
BH50AK0016400000000000000                EMMONAK                       AK7 941NAKAST01003030020A 2021120100000081900   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        EMMONAK                       158            
BH50AK0016600000000000000                HOUSTON                       AK6 941NAKAST01003030020A 2021120100000252300  38000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        HOUSTON                       170            
BH50AK020045Y000000000000                ANCHORAGE                     AK7 946NAKAST01003030020A 20211201000000000000  0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        ALCOHOL BEV CONTROL BRD                      
BH50AKASP0000000000000000                ANCHORAGE                     AK0 944NAKAST01003030020A 2021120100000000000    000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        STATE TROOPERS                               
BH50AKAST0000000000000000                                              AK8E944N         3030020A         00000000000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        STATE TROOPERS, JUNEAU        110            
BH50AKAST0100000000000000        20210101Anchorage                     AK8A944N         3030020AA        000266838000  0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021ZZIZ    ALASKA STATE TROOPERS                        
IR50AKAST0100D42A5WL-XNTD20210815N300100U2900011011I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000000 
IR50AKAST0100GB2WKBBM619G20210714N300201I13A0022011IL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0020000100 
IR50AKAST0100GB2WKBBM61NG20210714N300101I13C0015811I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100 
BH50AKAST0600000000000000                                              AK8E944N         3030020A         00000000000   0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        STATE TROOPERS, BETHEL        050            
BH50AKAST1500000000000000                Anchorage                     AK9E944N         3030020A         00000000000  38000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        STATE TROOPERS HQS, ANCHORAGE 020            
BH98AKATF0200000000000000                                              FS               3030020A         000000000000  0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        BUREAU OF ATF ANCHORAGE                      
BH50AKDI00100000000000000                                              AK0 94 N         00000000         00000000000    000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        KATMAI NM                                    
BH50AKDI00200000000000000                                              AK0 94 N         00000000         00000000000    000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        MOUNT MCKINLEY NP                            
BH50AKDI00300000000000000                                              AK0 94 N         00000000         00000000000    000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        SITKA NHP                                    
BH50AKDI00400000000000000                                              AK0 94 N         00000000         00000000000    000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        GLACIER BAY NM                               
BH98AKFBIAN00000000000000                                              FS      DCFBIWA013030020A 20211201000000000000  0000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021        FBI, ANCHORAGE                               
BH01AL0010000000000000000        20210101BIRMINGHAM                    AL9A632N         3070010NA        000156865037 98000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      000000000000000000      0000000002021IIII    JEFFERSON                     073            
IR01AL001000027231GOYLCXV20211007N400101W13B0012011I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR01AL00100002H6W8M9H4K7 20210902N300101B13B0011545I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR01AL00100002W2JPU7Z7NXO20210413N200101B13A0011533I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR01AL00100002ZE6O-L326ST20210510N200101W13C0012012I       2900012012I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0010000100N
IR01AL00100003S0GHP4YMZSL20210822N300001W2900011511B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000100N
IR01AL0010000696A5PTV301Q20210909N300001W2900012285B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000001N
IR01AL00100008WDEJ-K1J6X020210202N100101W13A0011312I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR01AL0010000AZEKH18Y7HZ420210820N300101W13B0011511I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR01AL0010000D96IGAR23PU620211114N400101U23G0012011I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000000 
IR01AL0010000EM2MRVC3TUE220211116N400101U26F0012085I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000000U
IR01AL0010000H E193G07Q5P20210810N300101W13B0012012I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR01AL0010000HQ7G6OPPYP6S20210627N200001B35A0011311S                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000100N
IR01AL0010000HSCF7R8HWW3320211004N400101U23F0012085I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000000U
IR01AL0010000IE0DVPBMDOTC20210908N300100U2900012533I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000000 
IR01AL0010000IGAM8S0HFQ3C20210518N200101W13C0012312I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000100N
IR01AL0010000IQBI5Q-PGA2Q20210821N300002B23D0010711B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000200N
IR01AL0010000K-EYLL64K0Z520210625N200001B2900011511G                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0000000100N
IR01AL0010000O24G0XNSPMRX20210826N300101U23D0012041I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0010000000
```

Comment: Hi Kayla! I can get it into R using readr::read_fwf()! You might get some luck using the help file they link on cde.ucr.cjis.gov website too

Comment: Can you share the code with me that you used if you don't mind? I have been looking at the help file, but it doesn't provide information how to go about processing the data, it just gives a guide on how to structure the processing- if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, it's just `readr::read_fwf("/Users/my_username/Downloads/hate-crime-2021/2021_HC_NATIONAL_MASTER_FILE_ENC.txt")`

Comment: I was just able to import it, and my code looks like this:`# A tibble: 36,257 × 8
   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 BH50… AK1C… 0000… 0000… 0000… 0000… ANCH… NA   
 2 IR50… NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    0000…
 3 IR50… NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    0000…
 4 IR50… NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    0010…
 5 IR50… NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    0000…
 6 IR50… NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    0010…
 7 BH50… AK4 … 0000… 0000… 0000… 0000… FAIR… NA`

Comment: Is there a way that I can put headings on all of the batch headers and all of the incident reports?

Comment: yeah it's quite messy...just reading through the help file right now and it seems like the lines which start with BH and the ones which start with IR are essentially two different types of data. It seems like using a for loop is probably the way to go with this

Comment: Yes, they are two different kinds of data with two different widths-looking over my import right now I am seeing that it didn't import correctly. How do I do a for loop in R? I am not familiar with doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
file <- "/Users/pc/Downloads/hate-crime-2021/2021_HC_NATIONAL_MASTER_FILE_ENC.txt" 

library(tidyverse)

# read file in line by line, and make each line it's own string
df <- readLines(file) |>
        as_tibble() |>
        mutate(BH_group = cumsum(grepl("^BH", value))) # each time the line starts with BH, we know we are starting a new batch header row, so we increment our group number by 1

# since the data is fixed width, we use the separate_wider_position function to split the data into columns
# this is a huge pain to do, so I will leave doing the ir ones to you. You can find the details on how wide each column is meant to be in the help file you find when downloading the dataset

bh_df <- df[grepl("^BH", df$value),] |> 
  separate_wider_position(value, widths = c(type = 2, 
                                            state = 2,
                                            ori = 9,
                                            incident_number = 12,
                                            date_added = 8,
                                            date_ori_went_nibrs = 8,
                                            city = 30,
                                            state_abb = 2,
                                            pop_group = 2,
                                            country_div = 1,
                                            country_region = 1,
                                            agency_ind = 1,
                                            core_city = 1,
                                            covered_by_ori = 9,
                                            fbi_field_office = 4,
                                            judicial_district = 4,
                                            agency_nibrs_flag = 1,
                                            date_agency_inactive = 8,
                                            current_pop1 = 9,
                                            ucr_county_code1 = 3,
                                            msa_code1 = 3,
                                            last_pop1 = 9,
                                            current_pop2 = 9,
                                            ucr_county_code2 = 3,
                                            msa_code2 = 3,
                                            last_pop2 = 9,
                                            current_pop3 = 9,
                                            ucr_county_code3 = 3,
                                            msa_code3 = 3,
                                            last_pop3 = 9,
                                            current_pop4 = 9,
                                            ucr_county_code4 = 3,
                                            msa_code4 = 3,
                                            last_pop4 = 9,
                                            current_pop5 = 9,
                                            ucr_county_code5 = 3,
                                            msa_code5 = 3,
                                            last_pop5 = 9,
                                            master_file_year = 4,
                                            state_first_quarter_activy = 1,
                                            state_second_quarter_activity = 1,
                                            state_third_quarter_activity = 1,
                                            state_fourth_quarter_activity = 1,
                                            fed_first_quarter_activy = 1,
                                            fed_second_quarter_activity = 1,
                                            fed_third_quarter_activity = 1,
                                            fed_fourth_quarter_activity = 1,
                                            agency_name = 30,
                                            fips_county1 = 3,
                                            fips_county2 = 3,
                                            fips_county3 = 3,
                                            fips_county4 = 3,
                                            fips_county5 = 3
                                            ))
ir_df <- df[grepl("^IR", df$X1),]
# now do something similar, but with the widths for the ir data! :-)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 25,298 × 53
   type  state ori       incident_number date_added date_ori_went_nibrs city    
   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>           <chr>      <chr>               <chr>   
 1 BH    50    AK0010100 000000000000    "        " "        "          "ANCHOR…
 2 BH    50    AK0010200 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "FAIRBA…
 3 BH    50    AK0010300 000000000000    "        " "        "          "JUNEAU…
 4 BH    50    AK0010400 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "KETCHI…
 5 BH    50    AK0010500 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "KODIAK…
 6 BH    50    AK0010600 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "NOME  …
 7 BH    50    AK0010700 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "PETERS…
 8 BH    50    AK0010800 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "SEWARD…
 9 BH    50    AK0010900 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "SITKA …
10 BH    50    AK0011000 000000000000    "        " "20210101"          "SKAGWA…
# ℹ 25,288 more rows
# ℹ 46 more variables: state_abb <chr>, pop_group <chr>, country_div <chr>,
#   country_region <chr>, agency_ind <chr>, core_city <chr>,
#   covered_by_ori <chr>, fbi_field_office <chr>, judicial_district <chr>,
#   agency_nibrs_flag <chr>, date_agency_inactive <chr>, current_pop1 <chr>,
#   ucr_county_code1 <chr>, msa_code1 <chr>, last_pop1 <chr>,
#   current_pop2 <chr>, ucr_county_code2 <chr>, msa_code2 <chr>, …
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Once the IR dataframe has been processed, you can do the following:

```
left_join(ir_df, 
          bh_df |> select(ori, BH_group), by = "BH_group")
```

Left joins keep all rows of the first dataframe, and adds the columns of the second dataframe where the key matches (so in this case, it (for example) adds the ori of the first BH_group to all rows in ir_df where BH_group == 1.

Comment: This worked great, thank you! One more question. Is there a way I can link the incident reports to the batch header that precede it? There is a stipulation in the help file saying that "There may be hate crime incidents following the Batch Header that have a different ORI, but these should be considered part of the Batch Header in which they follow. Although positions 1-7 of the ORI will be identical in such instances, positions 8-9 can be different from the Batch Header’s ORI in the same positions."

Comment: Hi Kayla! I updated it!

Comment: I would do more, but 1. the number of columns is exhausting me, 2. I'm guessing you are learning to code/use R (?), so showing you how it's done and then getting you to do the rest is probably better than me spoonfeeding you haha

Comment: A couple of extra things - 1. a lot of the columns in the datasets are still strings after they are separated, but they're describing something which is a different type (e.g. `date_added` is meant to be a date). If you truly want to get this data tidy and ready for cleaning, you'll probably want to clean those up

Comment: 2. There's a bunch of columns in both which have the same data, but repeated in multiple columns for multiple incidents (e.g. `Note: Positions 42-59 occurs 10 times and redefines 42-221:`). This is bad practice, as it means (for example) if you wanted to find an incident where arson took place, you'd have to look across the first `UCR OFFENSE CODE`, the second one, the third etc.

Comment: you probably want to use `pivot_longer() on the data, though that can be something of a pain. If you are struggling with that, post another comment here, or make another question (and don't forget to add the head of your dataframe as a dput() to your question!)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Mark- and yes, I do have some R knowledge but I'm learning a lot as I go! I'll post another question or comment if I have any issues!